# Entity manager persist causes unnecessary updates

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have a following entity structure.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vertex")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Vertex implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "vertex_edge", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "vertex_id", referencedColumnName = "vertex_id")
}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "edge_id", referencedColumnName = "edge_id")
})
/** list of neighbor resources. */
private Collection<Edge> edges= new HashSet<Edge>();

public void setVertex(Vertex neighbourVertex)
{  Edge  edge = new Edge(this, neighbourVertex);
   edges.add(edge);
  }


@Entity
@Table(name = "edge")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "edgeType", discriminatorType =  DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Edge implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8827162781366388321L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "edge_id", nullable = false)
private long edgeID; 
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "start_vertex_id")
private Vertex start;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "end_vertex_id")
private Vertex end;
}
```

This is section how to save entity.

```
EntityManager em = EMFactory.getEM();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Vertex vertex1= new Vertex ();
        vertex1.setVertex(new Vertex ());
        em.persist(vertex1);
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
```

This is output. I could not understand update statement. When I persist a huge list of objects, this is a performance issue for me.

```
Hibernate: insert into vertex
Hibernate: insert into edge (end_vertex_id, start_vertex_id, edgeType) values (?, ?, 'edgeType1')
Hibernate: insert into vertex
**Hibernate: update edge set end_vertex_id=?, start_vertex_id=? where edge_id=?**
Hibernate: insert into vertex_edge(vertex_id, edge_id) values (?, ?)
```

Jpa Configuration

```
    <persistence-unit name="DBService"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="url of database" />

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100" />
            value="false" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Could you as well add your jpa configuration?

Comment: Added Jpa configuration

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your code when you save your `edge` object you make a `YouredgeEntity.setSomeProperty(..)`
this is how hibernate work when you save or  get a entity after this the entity stay in the session or we say is attached to the session and when you do some `setting` hibernate make `updating`.

Show your code when you save your objects for more help

Comment: I have added saving part. After saving entity, I am not setting any new property.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is strange because you have:

- an Edge with a vertex reference
- a Vertex with a many-to-many association to an Edge, hence an additional vertex_edge link table

I think you need to change the Edge to:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "start_vertex_id")
private Vertex start;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "end_vertex_id")
private Vertex end;
```

And Vertex to:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="start")
private Set<Edges> startEdges = new HashSet<Edge>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="end")
private Set<Edges> endEdges = new HashSet<Edge>();
```

Just make sure you synchronize both sides of the association.

Comment: I added setVertex function in Vertex class. It implements item1 and item 2.

Comment: Check my updated answer to get an understanding of how you need to restructure your mapping.

Comment: addEdge function is wrong. You are  adding a Vertex to  edge collections.

Comment: I took it out. You should provide a method to set both sides of the association and decide how you want to handle those relations. The previous mapping of yours was wrong anyway, so you might be interested in having an Edge a Vertex and an EdgeVertex entity to link the first two ones. Good luck with it.